# Make me understand this thread sync failure

Tags: java, multithreading

I'll cut it short.

Given this code:

```
public class Test {

private static long counter = 1000000;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    T t = new T();

    t.start();

    while(counter >= 0){
        counter--;
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
    System.out.println(t.isAlive());    

}

private static class T extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(counter > 0);

        System.out.println("end reached");



     }

   }    
 }
```

Why in the name of the gods doesn't T print "end Reached"? Counter goes down to -1 and t is alive. If I decrease the counter it sometimes work.

Comment: for me it prints `end reached` at least.

Comment: I guess this code is for learning, but just to point out this behaviour is implemented in the standard API in [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make counter `volatile`. Thread T is using a local copy.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. So, the new thread is given its own memory and all primitives gets copied to this memory, is that it? Should all primitives and data-structures that are used as flags or meant to be accessed through different threads be made volatile?

Comment: @Jake they don't necessarily need to be made volatile. For instance, you could wrap all accesses to them in a synchronized block; alternatively, you can use `Atomic*` classes. I strongly recommend grabbing a copy Java Concurrency In Practice, which explains all of these options.

Comment: To really get the full picture, it would be helpful to you to understand what happens when Java code gets compiled in Java byte code (.class files) as well as the JVM specification/requirement for cpu registers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register

Comment: I think I get it. The problem is multiple processors having different registers. When a variable is accessed and modified in one thread, on one processor, it doesn't necessarily write this back to the chache, or to the memory. Likewise the other thread might not read the variable from memory. Violate makes sure that when a variable is accessed it is fetched from memory and when modified, it's written back to memory. I just never expected to find these problems in any languages other than C and Assembler.